# why for..of is not working on this canonical function

Tags: javascript, iterator

I am having hard time understanding the concept of for..of loop.
i came across this canonical function which returns object, have next function means have iterator.

```js
function someFunction() {
  let n = 0;
  return {
    next() {
      n++;
      if (n <= 5) {
        return {
          value: n * n,
          done: false
        }
      }
      return {
        value: undefined,
        done: true
      }
    }
  };


}
let someStorage = someFunction();
for (let v of someStorage) {
  console.log(v);
}
```

why doesn't for..of loop works alone on it, why do we have to use [symbol.iterator]?

Comment: so even thou it has iterable it can' t be iterated ?

Comment: as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterator_protocol) ... *It is not possible to know reflectively whether a particular object implements the iterator protocol. However, it is easy to create an object that satisfies both the iterator and iterable protocols (as shown in the example below).

Doing so allows an iterator to be consumed by the various syntaxes expecting iterables. Thus, it is seldom useful to implement the Iterator Protocol without also implementing Iterable*

Comment: another thought, why should an object be considered iterable just because it happens to have a `next()` function - specifically *making* the object iterable using `symbol.iterator` makes far more sense to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, because the specification says so. See [Runtime Semantics: ForIn/OfHeadEvaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#_ref_4408). When `exprValue` is the object being iterated over (eg, `someStorage` in `for(let v of someStorage)`, it runs:

> d. Return ? GetIterator(exprValue, iteratorHint).

Where [GetIterator](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-getiterator) does, in the case of `for..of`:

> b. Otherwise, set method to ? GetMethod(obj, @@iterator).
>
> 4 Let iterator be ? Call(method, obj).
>
> 5 If Type(iterator) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.

Where `@@iterator` is `Symbol.iterator`, in the language of the spec.

So, `someStorage` *must* have a `Symbol.iterator` method on it, otherwise iteration using `for..of` will not be possible. Simply returning an object from the function is not sufficient.

It would work if you created an object with a `Symbol.iterator` property:

```js
function someFunction() {
  let n = 0;
  return {
    next() {
      n++;
      if (n <= 5) {
        return {
          value: n * n,
          done: false
        }
      }
      return {
        value: undefined,
        done: true
      }
    }
  };
}

const someIterableObject = { [Symbol.iterator]: someFunction };
for (let v of someIterableObject) {
  console.log(v);
}
```

You could also greatly simplify things by using a generator instead:

```js
function *someFunction() {
  let n = 1;
  while (n <= 5) {
    yield n ** 2;
    n++;
  }
}

const someIterableObject = { [Symbol.iterator]: someFunction };
for (let v of someIterableObject) {
  console.log(v);
}
```